# the method shouldAutorotate is called on the simulator and not called on a real device

Tags: ios

the method shouldAutorotate is called on the simulator and not called on a real device.
iOS 9 (maybe others as well but checked only with iOS 9)
using overridden methods.

Comment: By default, if you compile again iOS 9, you always autorotate on iPad. So there is no need for the runtime to check `shouldAutorotate`; the answer _must_ be yes.

Comment: how can one block that autorotation? and more important why simulator and real device is different?

Comment: You would have to opt out of iPad Multitasking.

Comment: How to do that? I don't need multitasking.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I didn't know about that feature. And the problem has been solved by unknown reason. I guess I changed something in plist file.